# During a Firebase outage is there a way to simulate this by running local code

Tags: javascript, firebase, error-handling

During a firebase outage my app had a very poor user experience with things just not loading. Is there a way to run some local code to simulate this experience so that my app doesn't crash and burn during the next outage? I'm currently using the javascript SDK.

[image: Errors from the app]

Comment: Put all your Firebase code behind some interface, then use a dependency injection framework to inject an instance of that interface that behaves the way you want.

Comment: You can use some sort of cache, following the hit and miss pattern....check if firebase is reachable when you are going to insert or update stuff, if not, pull the object into a queue, if becomes available and the size of the queue is greater than zero, pull those items on firebase, pop the item from the queue and, until we don't have more items on the queue.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to reproduce the results fairly easily by adding overrides to the socket connectors in my /etc/hosts file

```
127.1.1.1 s-usc1c-nss-215.firebaseio.com
127.1.1.1 s-usc1c-nss-222.firebaseio.com
```

You can pull this location from your network WS tab in chrome to see what needs to get overwritten
[image]